# How to restore data in P13nDialog fragment in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying P13nDialog fragment in XML view. I completed all functionality of sort , columns and filter.

Now I am trying cancel and restore button functionality like smart table setting fragment functionality.

I set json model for column , sort and filter but after changing in data it's not reflecting in json model.

Please tell me than how to achieve reset button functionality.

Below is my XML code :

```
Definition xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
    <P13nDialog id="id_SettingsFrg" ok="fnhandleOK" cancel="fnhandleCancel" showReset="true"
        reset="fnhandleReset" initialVisiblePanelType="columns">
        <panels>
            <P13nColumnsPanel id="id_Properties" addColumnsItem="fnonAddColumnsItem"
                changeColumnsItems="fnonChangeColumnsItem" type="columns"
                items="{Pro>/property}" title="Columns" >
                <items>
                    <P13nItem columnKey="{Pro>key}" text="{Pro>name}" visible="{Pro>visible}" />
                </items>
            </P13nColumnsPanel>
            <P13nSortPanel id="id_Sort" 
                type="sort"
                containerQuery="true"
                items="{Pro>/property}"
                title="Sort"
                sortItems="{So>/Sort}"
                updateSortItem="fnUpdateSort"
                addSortItem="fnAddSort"
                removeSortItem="fnRemoveSort" >
                <P13nItem columnKey="{Pro>name}" text="{Pro>name}" />
                <sortItems>
                    <P13nSortItem columnKey="{So>name}" operation="{So>order}" />
                </sortItems>
            </P13nSortPanel>
            <P13nFilterPanel id="id_filter" 
                type="filter"
                containerQuery="true"
                items="{Pro>/property}"
                title="Filter"
                filterItems="{Fl>/Filter}" >
                <P13nItem columnKey="{Pro>name}" text="{Pro>name}" type="{Pro>type}" />
                <filterItems>
                    <P13nFilterItem columnKey="{Fl>name}" operation="{Fl>option}" value1="{Fl>value}" />
                </filterItems>
            </P13nFilterPanel>
        </panels>
    </P13nDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Screen Shot :[image: screen shot of fragment]

thank you.

Comment: What do you have so far, any coding?

Comment: Is your json model in TwoWayBinding mode ? if yes, it should reflect changes

Comment: json model is in Two way binding only, but but it's not reflecting changes